# VBA creating date with strings

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to do simple tasks with date type but what I'm getting is not what I want. I would like to Split some cell value with delimiter and return string values to DateValue method.

My code

```
Dim str2() As String
str2() = Split(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value, ".")

Dim date1 As Date
date1 = DateValue(str(0) & "-" + str(1) & "-" & str(2))
```

What I'm trying to do is getting some specific date format. Date in the cell is formated like this : 26.05.14 (day.month.year) and I want to have format like this 2014-05-26(year-month-day). That's all. 
DateValue method returs me a date 2000-01-02.
I don't knwo how can I look into the str2() array to see what values are there after Split method. How can I do that ?

It seems VBA is completely different from VB.NET ... I'm not experienced with VBA. 
Thanks

Comment: what is the `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value` returning? Can you try:  `date1 = CDate(Replace(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value, ".", "/"))`

Comment: How can I check what does return `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value` ? When I point a mouse above `str2()` it doesn't prompt me anything after executing Split method. On the other hand when I try to see its values like this : `Dim strCheck1 As String
 strCheck1 = str2(0)` it gives me an compile error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: `date1 = CDate(Replace(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value, ".", "/"))` gives me "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: put `MsgBox Cells(activecell.row, 7).Value` as the first line in your `Sub` and tell us what the value is

Comment: Sorry. I made mistake because I didn't notice that seventh column was empty ... So `MsgBox Cells(activecell.row, 7)` returned me an empty value. When I tried `MsgBox Cells(activecell.row, 6)` which was not empty it returned me 26.05.14 value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing the return of your split into "str2" but then using the variable "str" into the DateValue input, which is not defined in your code (so it's empty). Avoid this kind of mistakes by putting "Option Explicit" on top of the project, in VBA is not compulsory like VB.NET but, indeed, optional. Here is the working code:

```
Dim str2() As String
str2 = Split(Range("A2").Value, ".")

Dim date1 As Date
date1 = DateValue(str2(0) & "-" & str2(1) & "-" & str2(2))
```

Comment: More general: DateValue(year & "-" + month & "-" & day)